# Where is my memory leak in this Doctrine 1.2 code?

Tags: php, doctrine

I am trying to reduce my memory usage on a large loop script so I made this little test. Using Doctrine I run this code:

```
$new_user_entry = getById($new_user_entries[0]['id']);
unset($new_user_entry);

$new_user_entry = getById($new_user_entries[1]['id']);
unset($new_user_entry);

function getById($holding_id)
{
    return Doctrine_Core::getTable('UserHoldingTable')->findOneById($holding_id);
}
```

But it leaves about another 50 KB in the memory for each time I do the getById and unset and I don't know why or how to change it. I have a loop that goes through thousands of these plus a couple other functions and this is creating an issue.

Comment: Do you have caching enabled in Doctrine ? http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/caching:query-cache-&-result-cache

Comment: If it is active by default, yes. But I have not turned it on myself.

Comment: Well, my point was, if caching is enabled, this would explain your memory leak - Doctrine would still have the objects cached because you would only have freed your references to them but not Doctrine's references.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but would it help if you were referencing it? `$new_user_entry =& getById($new_user_entries[0]['id']);`. Because you are copying the return value of getById into your new_user_entry variable, and are only unsetting this, while the original stays in memory. Might be totally wrong though, thats why I am not posting as an answer ;)

Comment: I will try that when I revisit this. My solution for now was to just write manual queries so that I have full control over what is loaded, works like a champ now.

Comment: @TilmanKöster Yep, it's wrong because PHP does this optimisations for you. You (almost) never have to pass variable as reference to gain performance. By doing this (premature optimisation) you can even get things worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a better solution so I gave up on Doctrine for this function and did a manual query with mysqli. This side stepped the issue and everything worked though not ideal.